# Filtering prices of stocks by the last day of the month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this Excel sheet with daily prices of some stocks. I want to calculate monthly returns from December 2017 to December 2019 with the last days of the month that the market was open. So I need to "erase" all the prices that are not from the last day of each month
I have tried using max function with filter function, but I'm a noobie on Excel so I don't really know how to use them.
Here is how the excel sheet looks like:

[image]
Hope you can help me, I want to learn and I wouldn't like to do it manually :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper column where you compare the result of the MONTH() function for the current row with the result of the MONTH() function for the following row:
[image: Screenshot illustrating use of proposed formula]

Answer (score 0):

You could just add another column and use EOMONTH like this `=A2=EOMONTH(A2,0)` and then just filter by `TRUE`

Comment: It doesn't work because not all months have the same number of days and I need the last day of the month that I have data of the prices (it's not always the 31th, it could be the 27th for example).

Comment: My mistake, please see my edited answer